Debian docker Error: libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
I am using docker to build a diesel rust application, For ease of deployment i am using the below DockerFile to create the image, but when i try to run it , it gives the error
/app/rest-jwt-rust: error while loading shared libraries: libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

i have tried installing libqp5 and libpqdev with my installation, but still having the same problem.
#build from latst rust version
FROM rust:latest as build

# install libpq, libsqlite and create new empty binary project
RUN apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends postgresql-common libpq-dev libpq5 libpq-dev libsqlite3-dev; \
    USER=root cargo new --bin app
WORKDIR /app

# copy manifests
COPY ./Cargo.toml ./Cargo.toml

# build this project to cache dependencies
RUN cargo build; \
    rm src/*.rs

# copy project source and necessary files
COPY ./src ./src
COPY ./migrations ./migrations
COPY ./diesel.toml .
COPY ./.env .

# rebuild app with project source
RUN rm ./target/debug/deps/rest_jwt_rust*; \
    cargo build --release

# deploy stage
FROM debian:buster-slim

# create app directory
RUN mkdir app
WORKDIR /app

# install libpq and libsqlite
RUN apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends postgresql-common libpq-dev  libpq5 libpq-dev libsqlite3-dev; \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# copy binary and configuration files
COPY --from=build /app/target/release/rest-jwt-rust .
COPY --from=build /app/.env .
COPY --from=build /app/diesel.toml .
COPY ./wait-for-it.sh .

# expose port
EXPOSE 8080
# run the binary
CMD ["/app/rest-jwt-rust"]


I'd think you need libpq5 in the final image, as in error while loading shared libraries: libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory when running rust app, but it looks like it's there.  (Is the apt-get install step actually succeeding?  Try changing ; to && in that command to avoid suppressing errors.)

Always use && instead of ; if you care whether the commands succeed.

Also does your application depend on Debian Buster specifically? This is two releases old; you should be using Bookworm.

using libpq-dev during build and libpq5 for deploy and upgrading to bookworm made it work.
